# Facebook API - OAUTH login screen retains user email address

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-oauth

I have a public-facing web app that will be in a kiosk-like environment.  The app requires users to log in with Facebook in order to interact with the app.  I am not requiring users to register or to sign up for the site, but rather just log in so the app will have access to their basic info.

This works perfectly, but the issue is when a user logs out and the app is ready for the next user to log in, the previous user's email address is in the OAUTH form.

Is there any way to keep this from being persistant?

EDIT:
To log in, users are being redirected to the Facebook OAuth Dialog page.  Once the user logs in it redirects back to the app.  It's not really "authenticating" for the app, I am just using Javascript to show the app content once the Facebook JS API detects that a user is logged-in.

**Edit**

some reason I cannot log in with my account "kevinj". Anyway, I should have been more specific in regard to the setting of this app. It is an iPad web app and the tablet device will be handed out to users for interaction and gathering data.

I have "fixed" this issue by forcing FB to use the desktop browser based OAUTH dialog instead of the Touch version. This allows the user to un-check the "keep me logged in" option and clear out their info after log out.

Thanks for the suggestions and input. I wish I could close this question out but can't log in to my account.

Answer (score 1):

Sine you are on a Kiosk-like environment, I suppose you have access to the browser's options?

If that's the case then I think turning of form history will do the trick. (Firefox [example](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Form%20autocomplete?s=auto%20complete&as=s#w_prevent-firefox-from-storing-form-entries))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "autocomplete="off"" to the HTML field?

Comment: I can't do this as the login field is on the Facebook OAUTH Dialog page.  It's not mine to edit.